# Create a details page from API in Wordperss

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api

I'm creating a project in Wordpress, and are using api to get information into the site.
I have created a JavaScript file to fetch the api information.
This api has images in each result. What I want to do, is to click on one image that directs me to a (created) detail page that has more information about that specific result (This is a page I want to create myself).
I am relative new to Wordpress, so I hope I have done it right so far.

**Here is my code in JS**

```
const siteID = window.gamerRevData.siteID; // gamerRevData from functions.php

for(let i=2; i < 7; i++) {

    let gameUrls = fetch("https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=" + i).then(res => res.json());

    const retrieveAll = async function() {
        let results = await Promise.all([gameUrls]);
        let gameResults = results[0].results;
 
        for(let j=0; j < gameResults.length; j++) {

            console.log(gameResults[j]);

            const gamePlatforms = gameResults[j].platforms;
            const gameName = gameResults[j].name;
            const gameSlug = gameResults[j].slug;
            const gameImg = gameResults[j].background_image;
            const gameRating = gameResults[j].rating;
            const gameRelease = gameResults[j].released;
            const gameID = gameResults[j].id;

            function htmlOutput () {
                
                gameList.innerHTML += `
                <a href=' **LINK TO A DETAILS PAGE ABOUT THE GAME** >'
                 <img width='480' src='${gameImg}' alt=${gameSlug}>
                 <li>${gameName}</li>
                 <li>${gameRating}</li>
                 <li>${gameRelease}</li>
                </a>
                `
            }

           for(let k=0; k < gamePlatforms.length; k++) {
                let platformID = gamePlatforms[k].platform.id;

                // Playstation 5
                if(platformID == 187 && siteID == "5") {
                    htmlOutput();
                }

                // Playstation 4
                if(platformID == 18 && siteID == "8") {
                    htmlOutput();
                }

                // Xbox S/X
                if(platformID == 186 && siteID == "10") {
                    htmlOutput();
                }

                // Xbox One
                if(platformID == 1 && siteID == "12") {
                    htmlOutput();
                }

                // Nintendo Switch
                if(platformID == 7 && siteID == "14") {
                    htmlOutput();
                }

                // PC
                if(platformID == 4 && siteID == "16") {
                    htmlOutput();
                }
            } // end loop
        } // end loop
    }(); // end async function
} // end loop
```

**and the page.php**

```
<?php 
    get_header();
    
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <ul id="gameList">
            
        </ul>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Sapiente necessitatibus minima blanditiis dicta harum dolore quisquam, 
        voluptatem ducimus expedita corporis voluptas at autem fuga repellat perspiciatis!
         Dolore eum nulla corrupti?</p>

    <?php }

    get_footer(); 
 
?>
```

**and functions.php**

```
<?php

function gamerRevolutionFiles () {
    wp_enqueue_script("gamer_revolution_script", get_theme_file_uri("/js/script.js"), NULL, 1.0, true); // JavaScript
    wp_enqueue_style("bootstrap", "//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"); // Bootstrap
    wp_enqueue_style("gamer_revolution_styles", get_stylesheet_uri()); // CSS
    wp_localize_script("gamer_revolution_script", "gamerRevData", array(
        "siteID" => get_the_ID()
    ));
}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "gamerRevolutionFiles");

function gamerRevolutionTitle() {
    add_theme_support("title-tag");
}

add_action("after_setup_theme", "gamerRevolutionTitle");
```

Not sure if there is anything more you need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to create real WordPress pages based on 3rd-party API data then you got it all wrong. You need to write backend PHP function that retrieves the data in background (preferably as a wp-cli script) and creates all the pages and structure you need. After that it would be relatively easy to display everything you need on frontend, exactly the way you need it

Comment: okay, thanks. I'll try it.